# GCC & G++ NOT INSTALLING

Tags: release-juno, software-installation

After running

```
barefaced@barefaced-HP-Laptop-15-bw0xx:~$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 build-essential : Depends: gcc (>= 4:7.2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: g++ (>= 4:7.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

GCC & G++ is not getting installed

Comment: Please help me understand, what do you need to install? Are you trying to install `gcc` & `g++`? From the attached terminal snap, i can see you are trying to install `build-essential` not `gcc` or `g++`.

Comment: Error says you can't install `build-essential` because it your system don't have `gcc` and `g++` which are two of packages `build-essentail` depends on.

Comment: If you want to install `gcc` and `g++` you need to execute `sudo apt install gcc` and `sudo apt install g++`. Please let me know what you are trying to do actually so that I can assist you.